# How to read a cell value randomly using random function from an excel file in Java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, random, data-driven-tests

I have an excel sheet having 10 entries , 0-9 rows & 0 columns. I want to read a random value from the cell of (5,0) ex (row, column) using random function ?
Below is the code i tried !

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C://Users//logasaravanan.g//Desktop//seleniumtest.xls");
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("xxxx");
Random rand = new Random();
int a= rand(sheet.getLastRowNum());
HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(a);
System.out.println("Running test case " + row.getCell(0).toString());
```

Comment: this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt())

```
int row = rand.nextInt(sheet.getLastRowNum());
```

Your error lies in the fact that you try to use your rand `Object` as a method.
That's not how it works. Your rand is a `Object` of the type [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.htm)

You then access methods ON that object to achieve your goals. You can kinda see it as a toolbox.

By doing `Random rand = new Random()` you're getting your toolbox off the shelf.
Then you can use tools that are IN the toolbox, like `rand.nextInt`

Comment: If this question helped you you can consider upvoting or accepting this answer, as an idication for future people having a similar problem that this solved your problem.