# How to read random cell data form excel in java

Tags: java, excel

I have excel sheet with two columns, first column has 50 first names and second column has 50 last names. I want to read random first name and random last name everytime I call excel sheet. Here is my generic method for accessing both the columns

```
public void getCellData(String sheetName) {
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        Iterator iterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();
            Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
                String cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(cellData);
            }   }   }
```

Above code will display all first and last names. Now that I have access to the names how do I randomly select the first and last name ?

I tried this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237654/how-to-read-a-cell-value-randomly-using-random-function-from-an-excel-file-in-ja), but it was more about intergers.

Any help please on how to randomly select cell data using java ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do by following

```
    public void getCellData(String sheetName) {
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        int randomRowIndex = new SecureRandom().nextInt(sheet.getLastRowNum()) % sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(randomRowIndex);
        Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
            String cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println(cellData);
       }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.cellIterator()" because "row" is null` error @mystery

Comment: @GSN what is the row number and how many rows are there in the excel?

Comment: Also updated my answer to limit random number within row limit

Comment: Your updated script worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GSN if it worked then you can accept this answer for future user

Comment: Done! Thank you

Comment: @GSN it is not accepted yet